# Translate Matlab eig to R eigen

Tags: r, matlab

How to translate this MATLAB code

```
[W LA] = eig(Matrix)
```

in to R code, I have this

```
w= eigen(Matrix)$vectors
```

But how to obtain the ‘LA’ matrix

Comment: ...from the "See Also" section of `?eigen`.

Answer (score 1):

```
LA= eigen(Matrix)$values %*% diag(length(Matrix))
```